# Answering your own question, which has your own bounty

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted [This Question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10756/miniature-schnauzer-thicker-hair-grow-after-skin-problems) a while ago, after receiving 0 feedback I decided to put a bounty on it, still no feedback. During the weekend I had some free time from my work projects and decided to dig in into the issue, I was able to find a very good reason/answer as to why my "issue" was happening. So I decided to post an answer.

Is this okay with Pet's Regulations? I haven't accepted my own answer, in hopes someone will post something far more better than what I was able to find.

Comment: @JohnCavan the time expired, what happens to that bounty? Does it get deleted, does it come back to me, does it just stays there until I award it to someone else?

Comment: You lose the bounty permanently, it won't be awarded to your answer as far as I know.

Comment: Just wondering what would happen, I already recovered that rep by participating in the site @JohnCavan , thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is completely OK, and encouraged to answer your own questions.  When I do it (on pets.SE), I usually don't accept my answer for the same reasons you have given.  If a month or so passes, and still no other answers, I will mark it as accepted to keep 'community' from bouncing it to the top of the active list.

On more technical sites (i.e. Stack Exchange) or if you are pretty sure no one else is going to be able to answer the question, go ahead and accept it.  If someone comes along latter with a better answer than you have, you can mark their answer as accepted.

Comment: and do you also get the bounty you yourself is offering?